# Bluetooth not working but WiFi is after force shutdown

Tags: boot, bluetooth, rfkill

So I was booting into my Ubuntu machine (dualbooted with Win10) and it was completely frozen. Held power down and forced shutdown to fix it. This worked fine, booted back in and everything was working okay.

All of a sudden, my bluetooth no longer works. My wifi is working (although the software updater seems to think that it is not). I ran rfkill and nothing is blocked, and after running dmesg I got these errors back:

```
[ 13.397341] Bluetooth: hci0: sending initial HCI reset command failed (-110)
[ 48.066229] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ 48.817776] FAT-fs (sda): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[ 103.605373] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[ 111.700870] Bluetooth: hci0: sending initial HCI reset command failed (-110)
```

What should I do?

Comment: After a power outage or any other forced shutdown, I always opt for a `fsck` (file system check) performed from a 'live' media before I try booting a system (your third line of post mentions a fsck is needed).  If i think system is frozen, I firstly try switching to a text terminal (eg. ctrl+alt+F4) to login there, if that doesn't work I use SysRq keys to tell the system to shudown clearly (eg. REISUB or like options), and power-off is a last resort (for if that's used, I need to `fsck` first..).  How I `fsck` may differ on the the type of file-system(s) in use

Comment: So should I run fsck on my system now? I'm posting from it at the moment, but when I went to run it, it said it would cause damage as my filesystem is already mounted. (Sorry for the stupid questions)

Comment: Yes, but don't `fsck` a mounted file-system.  As per my first comment, I don't boot my system until after the `fsck` which as stated is using 'live' media (Ubuntu install media; or something handy of same vintage or newer). I select the "Try Ubuntu" (or equivalent option; eg. "Start Lubuntu" etc) so the file-systems I want to `fsck` are **not** being used. I only attempt booting the installed systems after that.

Comment: Okay I will make a boot usb and try it from there. Thanks.